# Authentication in Node JS soap request

Tags: node.js, soap, strong-soap

I am using strong-soap (https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-soap) for consuming wsdl from Node JS

I have a wsdl with header like below:-

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://xyz.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24" xmlns:wsu="http://secure.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>userid</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://pwdtext">password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I need to add this header information while creating client.
I tried like

```
var url = "test?wsdl";
soap.createClient(url,  {wsdl_headers: {"Username": "username","Password":"password"} }, function(err, client) { 
    //some logic
});
```

But every time I was getting soap fault "Authentication Failed".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue trying to pull data.

my mistake was that in the options of the createClient method is was using **headers** instead of **wsdl_headers**

also set the same authentication on the client before any method is called

my code looks as

```
var url = 'https://datahere?wsdl';
var httpOptions = {
  wsdl_headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('username' + ':' + 'password').toString('base64')
  }
};

soap.createClient(url, httpOptions, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    response.status(401).end();
  } else {
    var requestArgs = {
      Method1: 'dummyData',
      Method2: ''
    };

    // client.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity('password', 'password'));
    client.addHttpHeader('customHeader1', 'words');
    client.addHttpHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + new Buffer('username-app-maker' + ':' + 'password').toString('base64'));
    client.GETSOAPMETHOD(requestArgs, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }

      console.log('i found ' + result);
      response.send(result);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29036312/6202058), wsdl_header object is expecting a key 'Authentication'

So try running the following code:

```
var url = 'test?wsdl';
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("your username" + ":" + "your password").toString("base64");

soap.createClient(url, { wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth} }, function(err, client) {
});
```

Comment: I tried the above method. It didn't work. Still I am getting soap fault error.